# Synchronizing message sending and receiving AGSXMPP

Tags: c#, .net, xmpp, agsxmpp

I am developing a communication layer between client and server using XMPP in c#. The requirement is to send message from client and halt execution until a reply is received from server. Is there any way of doing that using agsXMPP?

Another thing is I don't want server to synchronize the message sending/receiving. It should be only client waiting for the reply. Server should work asynchronously.

Please help if there is any thing available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard [XMPP IQ](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-semantics-iq) requests with your own payload. IQs are specially designed for situations when reply is required.

In agsXMPP there is an [IqGrabber](https://github.com/meebey/agsxmpp/blob/master/agsxmpp/IqGrabber.cs) class, which can be used to send query and perform callbacks on the query response.